Does isometry on PSD matrices preserve eigenvalues?
Let $S$ be the set of symmetric matrices and $T: S\rightarrow S$ be a linear isometry. Moreover, let $T$ be a bijection from the space of PSD matrices to the set of PSD matrices. Must $T$ preserve eigenvalues? In other words, does there exist an orthogonal matrix $Q \in O(n)$ such that $T(X) = QXQ^T$ for any $X\in S$?

Isometry of which metric?

The Frobenius norm

$T$ must also be linear?

I forgot to say linear isometry, but yes.

The question can be reduced to whether the isometry group of the symmetric space $PGL(n,\mathbb R)/PO(n)$ is $PGL(n,\mathbb R)$ and this should be true, it should definitely be in one of Helgason's books and was already known to Poincaré for $n=2$. Tagging this with symmetric-spaces and lie-algebras to get attention from the right people.

@BartMichels: You are almost right, you should also add Cartan involutions for $n>2$.

Ok I commented too quick and don't see how to make my comment work, but see below for a proof.

The assumption can be slightly weakened. We may assume that $T$ is defined only on the set of all real PSD matrices, such that $T$ preserves Frobenius norm and is positively linear (i.e., $T(aA+bB)=aT(A)+bT(B)$ for any $a,b\ge0$ and any PSD matrices $A$ and $B$).
As usual in linear algebra literature, let $E_{ij}$ be the matrix whose only nonzero element is a $1$ at the $(i,j)$-th position, and $E$ be the all-one matrix, i.e., $E=\sum_{i,j}E_{ij}$.
With our weaker assumption, $T$ must also preserve Frobenius inner product. Therefore, for every orthogonal matrix $U$, the family $\left\{T(UE_{11}U^\top),T(UE_{22}U^\top)\ldots,T(UE_{nn}U^\top)\right\}$ must be orthonormal and hence commuting. Thus the matrices in this family can be simultaneously orthogonally diagonalised. But then the inner product preservation property of $T$ implies that this family must be an orthonormal set of rank-one orthogonal projections. Hence there exists an orthogonal matrix $V_U$ such that $T(UE_{11}U^\top)=V_UE_{11}V_U^\top$. It follows from the positive linearity of $T$ that $T(UDU^\top)=V_UDV_U^\top$ for all nonnegative diagonal matrices $D$. By redefining $T$ as $X\mapsto V_I^\top T(X)V_I$, we may assume that $T(D)=D$ for every diagonal nonnegative diagonal matrix $D$.
For any PSD matrix $Y$, since $\langle T(Y),D\rangle=\langle T(Y),T(D)\rangle=\langle Y,D\rangle$ for all nonnegative diagonal matrices $D$, the map $T$ must preserve the diagonal elements of $Y$. In particular, $T(E)$ has a diagonal of ones. As $E=UE_{11}U^\top$ for some orthogonal matrix $U$, $T(E)=V_UE_{11}V_U^\top$ is also a rank-one matrix. Therefore $T(E)=uu^\top$ for some vector $u$ whose elements are $\pm1$. So, by redefining $T$ as $X\mapsto \operatorname{diag}(u)\,T(X)\,\operatorname{diag}(u)$, we may further assume that $T(E)=E$.
Let $\mathcal Z$ be the set of all PSD matrices $Z$ of the form $P\left(\pmatrix{1&c\\ c&1}\oplus0\right)P^\top$ for some permutation matrix $P$ and $c=\pm1$. For each such $Z$, let $D=P(0\oplus I_{n-2})P^\top$. Since $D$ is a nonnegative diagonal matrix, we have $T(D)=D$ and
$
\langle T(Z),D\rangle
=\langle T(Z),T(D)\rangle
=\langle Z,D\rangle
=0.
$
Hence $T(Z)=P\left(\pmatrix{a&b\\ b&a}\oplus0\right)P^\top$ for some $a$ and $b$. As $T$ preserves diagonal elements, $a$ must be equal to $1$. Therefore
$
2(1+b)
=\langle T(Z),\,E\rangle
=\langle T(Z),\,T(E)\rangle
=\langle Z,\,E\rangle
=2(1+c),
$
meaning that $b=c$ and $T(Z)=Z$.
Now, for any PSD matrix $X$, let $k=\sum_{i<j}|x_{ij}|$. Then $X+kI=D+\sum_{i<j}|x_{ij}|Z_{ij}$ for some nonnegative diagonal matrix $D$ and matrices $Z_{ij}\in\mathcal Z$. Therefore
\begin{align*}
T(X)+kI
&=T(X)+T(kI)\\
&=T(X+kI)\\
&=T\left(D+\sum_{i<j}|x_{ij}|Z_{ij}\right)\\
&=T(D)+\sum_{i<j}|x_{ij}|T(Z_{ij})\\
&=D+\sum_{i<j}|x_{ij}|Z_{ij}\\
&=X+kI
\end{align*}
and we obtain $T(X)=X$ for all PSD matrices $X$. Consequently, if we revert the two previous redefinitions of $T$, we conclude that the original $T$ is given by $X\mapsto QXQ^\top$ for some orthogonal matrix $Q=V_I\operatorname{diag}(u)$.

I think this argument works. I will prove successively that $T$ preserves the following:

rank of positive semidefinite matrices
rank $1$ projections
commuting matrices

It will follow that $T$ is conjugation by an orthogonal matrix.
Lemma: $T$ preserves the rank of PSD matrices.

Because $T$ is a continuous bijection on the PSD matrices, it preserves
the interior, which consists of the rank $n$ PSD matrices. We proceed
by induction, going by decreasing rank, by using the following fact:
For a matrix $X \in PSD(n)$ with $rank(X) \leq k$ the following are equivalent:

$rank(X) = k$.
The set $$\{ Y \in PSD(n): rank(X+Y) \leq k \}$$ is closed under addition.

Accepting this fact, and knowing that the set of matrices of rank $\leq n-1$ is preserved, we get by induction that the set of matrices of rank $\leq k$ is preserved for all $k$.

Lemma: $T$ preserves rank $1$ projections

Because the rank $1$ projections are the rank $1$ matrices $P$ with $Tr(P^2) = 1$, that is, with norm $1$.

Lemma: $T$ preserves commuting matrices

Let $A, B$ be symmetric commuting matrices. They can be diagonalized
simultaneously so we may assume they are already diagonal. Consider
the $n$ diagonal rank $1$ projections. It suffices to show that they
still commute after applying $T$, because then their images under $T$
can be diagonalized simultaneously and then so can $A$ and $B$. This follows from the following fact:
If $A, B$ are projections with $Tr(AB) = 0$, then $A$ and $B$ commute.
Indeed, we may assume $A$ is diagonal. Because $Tr(AB) = 0$, $B$ has
zeroes on the diagonal where $A$ has ones. Because $B$ is PSD, it must
have zeroes also in the corresponding rows and columns. Therefore $B$
commutes with $A$.

Proof of the main result.

Consider the diagonal matrices. Because $T$ preserves rank $1$
projections and the diagonal ones commute, we may assume that $T$
sends the set of diagonal matrices to itself, and therefore permutes the
diagonal rank $1$ projections. By conjugating by a permutation matrix,
we may even assume that $T$ fixes these projections, and therefore
fixes the diagonal subalgebra. By conjugating, we can apply this argument to any commutative subalgebra, and it is then clear that $T$ preserves eigenvalues (with multiplicity) and therefore determinants.
We will show that now $T$ must be conjugation by a matrix with $\pm 1$s on the diagonal.
Consider the matrix $E_{ij}$ with a $1$ in positions $(i, j)$ and $(j,i)$ and zeroes elsewhere. Consider the diagonal matrix $D_{ij}$ with
ones in positions $i$ and $j$. Then $D_{ij}+E_{ij}$ is positive
semidefinite and therefore so should $D_{ij} + T(E_{ij})$. So
$T(E_{ij})$ has zeroes except in the four entries whose row and column
index is $i$ or $j$. But $T(E_{ij})$ is orthogonal to the diagonal
matrices and the sum of the squares of the entries is $2$, which
forces $T(E_{ij}) = \pm E_{ij}$.
Call $R_{ij}$ the diagonal matrix with $-1$ in positions $i, j$ and
$1$ elsewhere.
By conjugating with the matrices $R_{1j}$ we may assume now that $T$
fixes the matrices $E_{1j}$. We now show that $T$ must be the
identity.
If not, we may find a central submatrix of the form $$\begin{pmatrix}0
 & 1 & 1 \\1 & 0 & 1 \\1 & 1 & 0\end{pmatrix}$$ that is sent to
$$\begin{pmatrix}0 & 1 & 1 \\1 & 0 & -1 \\1 & -1 & 0\end{pmatrix}
 \,.$$ But the first has determinant $2$ and the second has determinant
$-2$, which is a contradiction.

